# gnuradio: Sampling at the middle of the bit

Tags: synchronization, resampling, gnuradio

I am trying to design a GFSK receiver using gnuradio and LimeSDR. To do so, I am using the grc file [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4bwo.png). The file sink directs to a logfile that will contain the received bits. This file is read by MATLAB where more processing is performed (A preamble + data is detected there). The rational resampler serves the purpose of resampling the bitstream so that each bit is only sampled one time (and thus only 1 bit is sent to MATLAB, instead of 50 bits per bit - if that makes sense)

The current design works but only about 85% of the packets are received, which means that 15% of the preambles sent aren't even detected.

By saving a .wav file upstream of the rational resampler and comparing it to the log file downstream of the resampler at a time where reception failed, it has become clear that the problem occurs during the resampling since the .wav file is perfectly fine and contains the correct bits, but the resampled log file does not for that failed instance (when the reception was sucessful the log file matches the .wav file).

As a result, I conclude that the resampling is sometimes sampling the bitstream incorrectly (probably at the bit edges), so I ask how can I force the resampler block - or any other - to sample the bits correctly? I have looked at the symbol sync block but it required a triangular wave, and I cant produce one since I can't predict where the middle of the bit is. If anybody could help I would be grateful!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

A little bit more explanation of the receiver structure you can find here:
https://wirelesspi.com/fsk-demodulation-in-gnu-radio/.
Generally speaking the subsystem, responsible for right timing of the sampling of the symbol is "timing(aka symbol) clock synchronization system". As there is difference between transmitter's an receivers' oscilators, the "right" time changes. The timing clock constantly adjust right time. The discussion, after publication on the link provided, sugests that clasical symbol synch block could be used. You could give a try and share results.

Comment: Thank you Ivan for the provided links, they were helpful but I still wasn't able to find a solution for my problem. I have implemented the symbol sync block but am unable to tell if it is doing what it is supposed to, although I suspect it isn't since I'm getting a lot of lost packets